# PHP MySQL using Latin1(iso-8859-1) despite UTF-8 settings

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, latin1

Once again I have a weird and tricky problem.

I've been working with converting my MySQL databases (and everything else on my server for that matter) to UTF-8 to avoid having to convert text when getting and putting text into the different databases.

I think I've partially succeeded because `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%'` returns:

```
character_set_client utf8 
character_set_connection utf8 
character_set_database utf8 
character_set_filesystem binary 
character_set_results utf8 
character_set_server utf8 
character_set_system utf8
```

But still `mysql_client_encoding($con);` returns `latin1` and in the output every special character is replaced with �. My conclusion is that the client or the connection between PHP and the MySQL database is using latin1 even though I've been specifying utf-8 in the document header and in my.ini with the following code:

```
character-set-server = utf8
character-set-client = utf8
default-character-set = utf8
```

**edit:** I've added the settings above under both [client], [mysqld] and [mysql]

When I use `mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8;');` or `mysql_set_charset("utf8");` the text shows properly but for me that's not a sollution, just a temporary fix.

Does anyone know how to force PHP (or whatever it is reverting to latin1) to use utf-8?

I should mention that I'm using Windows 2003 Server and Apache 2.

Comment: I should point out that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are considered obsolete and should no longer be used. The PHP manual recommends using either the equivalent `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library instead.

Answer (score 2):

> I've been working with converting my MySQL databases (and everything
>   else on my server for that matter) to UTF-8 to avoid having to convert
>   text when getting and putting text into the different databases.

You would still have to make sure the target database (or system) is setup to use UTF-8 by default - and the library you are using to connect to is is using the correct character set. Just because data is in UTF-8 doesn't make it universally compatible.

> When I use mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8;'); or
>   mysql_set_charset("utf8"); the text shows properly but for me that's
>   not a sollution, just a temporary fix.

This is the proper solution. Since your connection's encoding determines how the data is received by your client (in this case, PHP).

To set it as default; you need to [configure MySQL appropriately](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-configuration.html) and then restart the server:

```
[client]
default-character-set=UTF8
```

Note that this affects *all* clients even the command line `mysql` client.

Comment: `To set it as default; you need to configure MySQL appropriately and then restart the server.`
 
I feel like I've already completed this step. Do you mean that SET NAMES is the only other way to do it? It feels like there should be a simpler way than to use SET NAMES every time I have to fetch something from the database.

Comment: You need to modify the `[client]` section. I have updated the question with the configuration variable you need from the [charset configuration page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-configuration.html) from the manual.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that I've already added that line under client as well as under mysqld and mysql. It doesn't seem to work.